# Command for tau symbol like this picture

Tags: symbols

Does anyone know the command for this symbol?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{euscript}
\begin{document}
\[
\tau\mathcal J, \mathfrak J, \EuScript J ?
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the symbol you circled is the Greek letter "tau"? Incidentally, what script is in use for the other characters? Arabic? Something else?

Comment: I think that symbol is the Greek letter "tau" but I'm not sure unfortunately. I use Arabic script for other characters

Comment: Do you have a PDF, to see what font is being used? It might be script or calligraphic, with those curves.

Comment: @Cicada, No I don't have.

Comment: I may be wrong, but it looks like a decorative Arabic Ha.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I will maybe use same "tau".

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL Indeed, mathematical hah, tailed or looped, are closest: 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer.

Various random `tau`s.

[image: tau]

No likely candidates.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!3}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[Colour=blue]
\setmathfontface\masana{Asana Math}
\setmathfontface\mdejavu{DejaVu Math}
\setmathfontface\mtgdeja{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}
\setmathfontface\mpagella{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfontface\mbonum{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
\setmathfontface\mschola{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\setmathfontface\mtermes{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfontface\mlatin{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfontface\mcambria{Cambria Math}
\setmathfontface\mfira{Fira Math}
\setmathfontface\mfreeserif{FreeSerif}
\setmathfontface\mlibert{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfontface\mnoto{Noto Sans Symbols}
\setmathfontface\mqui{Quivira}
\setmathfontface\mstixtwo{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfontface\mstixgen{STIXGeneral}
\setmathfontface\msymbola{Symbola}
\setmathfontface\mgaramond{\detokenize{Garamond-Math}}
\newcommand\mfsize{\Huge}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}


\newcommand\themassym{τ}%

\begin{document}
\section*{Sampling {\mfsize $\themassym $}}

\vspace{24pt}
    
\begin{tabular}{rccl}
XITS Math & \mfsize $\themassym$ & \mfsize $\mcambria \themassym$ & Cambria Math \\ 
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Asana Math & \mfsize $\masana {\themassym}$ & \mfsize $\mfira \themassym$ & Fira Math \\ 
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
DejaVu Math & \mfsize $\mdejavu \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mfreeserif \themassym$ & FreeSerif \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Bonum Math & \mfsize $\mbonum \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mlibert \themassym$ & Libertinus Math \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre DejaVu Math & \mfsize $\mtgdeja \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mnoto \themassym$ & Noto Sans Symbols \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Pagella Math & \mfsize $\mpagella \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mqui \themassym$ & Quivira \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Schola Math & \mfsize $\mschola \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mstixtwo \themassym$ &STIX Two Math \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Termes Math & \mfsize $\mtermes \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mgaramond \themassym$ & Garamond-Math \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Latin Modern Math & \mfsize $\mlatin \themassym$ & \mfsize $\msymbola \themassym$ & Symbola \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```